# Are there some other ways to solve a second PDE except DSolve?

Tags: functions, differential-equations

I have a  partial differential equation as follows:
$$\frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial t}=\text{Dp} \frac{\partial ^2p(x,t)}{\partial x^2}-\frac{p(x,t)-\text{p0}}{\tau }$$
What I try to do was to get its general solution by

```
DSolve[D[p[x, t], t] == -((p[x, t] - p0)/τ) + Dp D[p[x, t], {x, 2}], p, {x, t}]
```

However, the output returns what I have inputted, which means ***Mathematica*** cannot solve this PDE.

By looking up the [help document](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DSolveSecondOrderPDEs.html), I find that `DSolve` can only find the general solution for a restricted type of homogeneous linear second-order PDEs, that is, for such a linear second-order PDE as  $b \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x\, \partial y}+a \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}+c \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y^2}+d \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+e \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+f u=g$, only when `d=0`,`e=0`,`f=0` and `a`,`b` and `c` are all constants can we get the general solution.

I have tried this PED in **Maple**, and get a solution with conditions, but I don't know whether it is correct. The [help document](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DSolveSecondOrderPDEs.html) tells that the algorithm used by `DSolve` is not applicable in this case.

So, I wonder whether there exist some other ways or some packages to solve this PDE. If finding the general solution is impossible, is it possible to get a special solution?

Comment: You can refer to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29262/1871) answer.

Comment: None of us could make a living doing PDEs if it was that easy..

Comment: `and get a solution with conditions, but I don't know whether it is correct.` You can always substitute the solution back in the PDE and see if it satisfies it? Or since you used Maple, you can use pdetest http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=pdetest

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for this information. I'll try it again.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you!