# Can I take the Fourier transform of a PDE in both sides?

Tags: differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I want to know if it is possible to use a PDE in the function FourierTransform instead of a function.

Consider for example the simple case for the heat equation

```
Clear["Global`*"]
 uf=
 FourierTransform[
  Derivative[2, 0][u[x, t]] == Derivative[0, 1][u[x, t]], x, k]
```

I tried to run this but it doesn't work, is there any way I could make this work?

Als

Comment: Notice since _v12.3_ we can also use `BilateralLaplaceTransform` instead:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81164/1871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two steps. Let $U(\omega, t)$ be the Fourier transform of $u(x,t)$, and using the relation that $F \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} U(\omega,t)$ then we have (ps. I am using $\omega$ for your $k$ as I find it more clear)

```
Clear["Global`*"]
uf = FourierTransform[D[u[x,t],{x,2}],x,w]==FourierTransform[D[u[x,t],t],x,w]
uf = uf/.FourierTransform[u[x,t],x,w]->U[w,t]
uf/.FourierTransform[(u^(0,1))[x,t],x,w]->D[U[w,t],t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Using `ApplySides`:

```
uf = ApplySides[FourierTransform[#, x, w] &, D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] == D[u[x, t], t]]
```

And you do the following that @Nasser points out.