# To solve Cylinderical PDE

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

[image]
I want to solve this PDE.  I have tried to solve it with `NDSolve` but found error 'Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent'. Please help me to solve this problem: I am beginner in Mathematica. This is cylinderical PDE and in equation omega, lambda and fi have constant values i.e 2,3,4

This is what I have tried.

```
sol = NDSolve[{w^2 (1/p) (D[T[p, x] (D[T[p, x], {p, 1}]), {p, 1}]) 
      + D[T[p, x], {x, 2}] - 2 l (D[T[p, x], {x, 1}]) - 4 f^2 (T[p, x]) == 0,
T[p, 0] == 1, T[p, 1] == 1, T[0, x] == 10, T[1, x] == 1}, 
{T[p, x]}, {p, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: You might have a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14201/), though the answer might change within the month. In the meantime, you might look into [formatting on this site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Please post you (eventually non-working) code

Comment: sol = NDSolve[{w^2  (1/p) (D[T[p, x] (D[T[p, x], {p, 1}]), {p, 1}]) + 
     D[T[p, x], {x, 2}] - 2 l (D[T[p, x], {x, 1}]) - 
     4 f^2 (T[p, x]) == 0, T[p, 0] == 1, T[p, 1] == 1, T[0, x] == 10, 
   T[1, x] == 1}, {T[p, x]}, {p, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]

Comment: @Umer this does not seem to work?

Comment: thank you everyone for commenting. my codes are not working but now i am trying to solve it analytically as jens has mentioned. i wish i could do it numerically.

Comment: Why would you want to do numerically something you can do analytically?

Comment: This is problem related to diffusion and convection in catalyst pore and last term in equation is 'order of reaction' which is First order in this case. if i ll be able to solve it numerically i can solve it for any other higher order or complex reactions.

Answer (score 5):

As this is a separable problem, I would suggest doing the entire solution analytically instead of numerically. The separation of variables can be performed along the same lines as in [this closely related answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46777/245). I had to modify the steps slightly to get the variables `r` and `x` to separate properly, so I'll list the steps here.

First define the PDE and the separation ansatz. In `pde2`, I use `Expand` to get additional cancellations that `Simplify` alone doesn't achieve.

To enforce the boundary conditions, I use `Solve` after determining the general solution to each separated function (which are called `ax[x]` and `ar[r]` here). The separation constant is called $\kappa^2$ in this calculation:

```
pde = Function[
   c, ω^2 (D[c, {r, 2}] + D[c, r]/r) + D[c, {x, 2}] - 
    2 λ D[c, x] - 4 ϕ^2 c];

ansatz = ar[r] ax[x];

pde2 = Expand[Apply[Subtract, pde[ansatz]/ansatz == 0]]
```

> $$\frac{\omega ^2
>    \text{ar}''(r)}{\text{ar}(r)}+\frac{\omega ^2
>    \text{ar}'(r)}{r
>    \text{ar}(r)}+\frac{\text{ax}''(x)}{\text{ax}
>    (x)}-\frac{2 \lambda 
>    \text{ax}'(x)}{\text{ax}(x)}-4 \phi^2$$

```
ar[r] /. First@
  DSolve[Select[pde2, D[#, x] == 0 &] == κ^2, ar[r], r]

(*
==> 
BesselJ[0, (I r Sqrt[4 k^2 + κ^2])/ω] C[1] + 
 BesselY[0, -((I r Sqrt[4 k^2 + κ^2])/ω)] C[2]
*)

rSolution[r_] = % /. C[2] -> 0

(* ==> BesselJ[0, (I r Sqrt[4 k^2 + κ^2])/ω] C[1] *)

rCoefficients = First@Solve[rSolution[1] == 1, C[1]];

xSolution[x_] = ax[x] /. First@DSolve[
    Select[pde2, D[#, x] =!= 0 &] == -κ^2, ax[x], x, 
    GeneratedParameters -> B]

(*
==> 
E^(x (λ - Sqrt[-κ^2 + λ^2])) B[1] + 
 E^(x (λ + Sqrt[-κ^2 + λ^2])) B[2]
*)

xCoefficients = 
 First@Solve[xSolution[0] == 1 && xSolution[1] == 1, {B[1], B[2]}];

generalSolution[r_, x_] = 
 Simplify[rSolution[r] xSolution[x] /. xCoefficients /. rCoefficients]
```

> $$\frac{e^{(x-1) \left(-\sqrt{\lambda ^2-\kappa
>    ^2}\right)-\lambda } \left(e^{\sqrt{\lambda
>    ^2-\kappa ^2}+\lambda +\lambda  x}+e^{x
>    \left(2 \sqrt{\lambda ^2-\kappa ^2}+\lambda
>    \right)}-e^{(2 x-1) \sqrt{\lambda ^2-\kappa
>    ^2}+\lambda  (x+1)}-e^{\lambda  x}\right)
>    J_0\left(\frac{i r \sqrt{4 k^2+\kappa
>    ^2}}{\omega }\right)}{\left(e^{2
>    \sqrt{\lambda ^2-\kappa ^2}}-1\right)
>    J_0\left(\frac{i \sqrt{4 k^2+\kappa
>    ^2}}{\omega }\right)}$$

```
FullSimplify[pde[generalSolution[r, x]] == 0]

(* ==> True *)
```

In the expression `pde2`, selecting the terms that depend on one or the other variable has to be done with care, since there is also a term that doesn't depend on either of the variables ($-4\phi^2$). So instead of going with `FreeQ` to determine whether a variable occurs, I test for the derivatives of each term with respect to a given variable. That way, in `Select[pde2, D[#, x] =!= 0 &]` I only collect terms that really depend on `x`, whereas in `Select[pde2,D[#,x]==0&]` I include terms that depend on `r` or are constant.

Comment: Nice! It would be cool to write a wrapper to do this generically (i.e. as a possible attempt for an arbitrary PDE)?

Comment: thanks @jens is there any way to solve it numerically like using finite differences (method of lines)?

Comment: @chris That may be possible - although in general it may need more steps to insure that *Mathematica* multiplies by the correct powers of the *independent* variables to get the equivalent of `pde2`. I did manage to make it work in parabolic cylinder coordinates, so maybe I'll post an expanded version later.

Comment: What would be even nicer would be that the interpreter tries separating the problem in various coordinates. (though I guess the sets of possible coordinates depends on the geometry of the boundary condition). It just seems to me a more desirable feature for future versions of mathematica than some esoteric thing that have been introduced.

Comment: @Umer The problem is that you require boundary conditions on *both* ends of *both* intervals for your variables. The method of lines works only when you pose *initial* conditions, it doesn't know how to aim for the correct *final* condition.

Comment: @chris yes - the number of coordinate systems is finite (and they're already built in), but actually here we don't even need to go that far because the coordinates have already been chosen and it's just about identifying the separation step.

Comment: <http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14201/numerically-solving-an-inhomogeneous-partial-differential-equation> here is the problem solved by @mark McClure

Comment: @Umer Yes, that is a possible numerical approach that should work for you too. But he also clearly says that it's not the first choice of approach. Even the method of lines can in principle be used if you add another step that varies the initial conditions until the final conditions are met. But all these approaches are "band-aids." In your case, since it's analytically solvable I would maintain that that's the way to go.

Comment: @Umer By the way, I also implemented a relaxation method for this kind of problem in [Poisson solver using Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11768/245).